# Obtaining the vertex cosine similarity from a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Given a set of edges, how can the adjacency matrix of these edges be populated with each vertex pair's cosine similarity measure? Consider this edge set:

> edges = {TX -> R1, R1 -> R3, R3 -> R5, R5 -> RX, TX -> R2, R2 -> R4,
>   R4 -> R6, R6 -> RX, R1 -> R2, R2 -> R3, R3 -> R4, R4 -> R5,    R5 ->
>   R6, TX -> R7, TX -> R8, R7 -> R9, R9 -> R6, R9 -> RX,    R8 -> R6}

Comment: How do you want to deal with the fact that the graph is directed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
g = Graph[edges]; vlist = VertexList[g];

TableForm[
 Table[VertexCosineSimilarity[g, i, j], {i, vlist}, {j, vlist}], 
 TableHeadings -> {vlist, vlist}]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks!  Since the table is symmetric along the diagonal, how could the table be modified to only produce the values above (or below) the diagonal of 1s?

Comment: How does Mathematica generalize the concept to directed graphs?  The documentation claims that directed graphs are supported but it is not explained whether edge directions are just ignored.

Comment: What does `VertexCosineSimilarity[graph]` do?  It seems to compute this matrix for the undirected case. In the directed case, the result differs from that of your `Table`.  Is that a bug?

Comment: I just sent a report about this (CASE:4246003). I also wanted to say thank you for fixing so many bugs for 12.0.

Comment: Yes, Mathematica computes this measure as if the graph is undirected.